# Unstable wired home network

Tags: networking, router, wired-networking

I'm not a networking guy and I'm not sure what more I can do to troubleshoot / pinpoint the issues I'm seeing.

I have a fairly simple network layout as shown in the diagram below.

- The Router I can swap between my Ubiquiti EdgeRouter Lite (ERL) or a Linksys WRT54GL (wireless disabled).  The ERL is 10/100/1000.  The WRT54GL is 10/100.
- The Switch I can swap between a TP-Link 10/100/1000 or a D-Link 10/100.  They're both dumb (unmanaged) switches.

[image: Home network topology]

I had this setup with the ERL and TP-Link for a few months without issue.  Then the internal USB drive of the ERL self-destructed and I RMA-ed it.  While waiting for the replacement ERL I had the WRT54GL doing router duty.

When the replacement ERL arrived I updated the firmware and reloaded my backed up configuration.  I swapped it into the network and everything looked fine.  But then I started seeing instability and devices being dropped from the switch (the port on the switch going dark until I power-cycled the switch).

I'll describe some scenarios I'm seeing:

1. ERL, TP-Link, Devices C, E.  No Issue

   1.1. Add A & B in either order.  The port for either A, B, or the router will get shut off on the switch (link light goes on and off a few times, then stays off; interface flapping?).  Sometimes Device E gets shut off as well.
2. WRT54GL, TP-Link, Devices A, B, C, E.  No Issue
3. ERL, D-Link, Devices A, B, C, E.  No Issue

I don't have another gigabit router or other gigabit devices to add to the TP-Link switch to see if that triggers the same behavior.  I have tried swapping the cable for Device A (it seems to be the most likely device to get booted regardless of which port I connect it to).  I did a reset of the ERL and reconfigured it from scratch just to try something.

Device A and Device B are both Linux PCs (Mint, Ubuntu-derivative).  Looking through the logs I don't see anything unusual related to the network interfaces.  Just the expected up/down messages.

The issue only happens when I have all 3 gigabit devices active on the gigabit switch, but that may be a coincidence with some other cause.

My desired outcome is the ERL Router with the TP-Link switch as those were supposed to be upgrades to replace the WRT54GL and D-Link switch. Any ideas on how I can track down what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the gigabit switch replaced under warranty and the network is now stable again, so it seems to have been the culprit.

Comment: Pretty decent home setup glad you got it working again.